# Code works but still getting warning in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i am getting warning "Avoid mutating a prop directly", i know this can be solved through data property or computed usage like mentioned in [Vue Official Documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow). But i do not know how to change my code to any of those methods. Please help me with proper code to get rid of this Warning.

My Code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="track-rating">
    <span :key="note" v-for="note in maxNotes" :class="{ 'active': note <= rating || note <= hoveredNote }" @mouseover="hoveredNote = note" @mouseleave="hoveredNote = false" @click="rate(note)" class="material-icons mr-1">
    audiotrack
   </span>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
     name: "Rating",
     props: {
         rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        maxNotes: {
            type: Number,
            default: 3
        },
        hasCounter: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        itemId: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            hoveredNote: false
        };
    },
    methods: {
        rate(note) {
            if (typeof note === 'number' && note <= this.maxNotes && note >= 0)
                this.rating = this.rating === note ? note - 1 : note
            this.$emit('onRate', this.itemId, this.rating);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifing `rating` prop on the `rate` method, so to avoid the warning you should avoid to modify this prop, one easy solution although not very elegant is to make a local copy of your prop:

```js
<template>
  <div class="track-rating">
    <span :key="note" v-for="note in maxNotes" :class="{ 'active': note <= copiedrating || note <= hoveredNote }" @mouseover="hoveredNote = note" @mouseleave="hoveredNote = false" @click="rate(note)" class="material-icons mr-1">
    audiotrack
   </span>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
     name: "Rating",
     props: {
         rating: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        maxNotes: {
            type: Number,
            default: 3
        },
        hasCounter: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        itemId: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.copiedrating = this.rating;
    },
    data() {
        return {
            hoveredNote: false,
            copiedrating: null,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        rate(note) {
            if (typeof note === 'number' && note <= this.maxNotes && note >= 0)
                this.copiedrating = this.copiedrating === note ? note - 1 : note
            this.$emit('onRate', this.itemId, this.copiedrating);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify `this.rating` directly, just send the event and make the change in parent component....

```js
 methods: {
        rate(note) {
            if (typeof note === 'number' && note <= this.maxNotes && note >= 0) {
                const newRating = this.rating === note ? note - 1 : note
                this.$emit('onRate', this.itemId, newRating);
            }
        }
    }
```

...then in parent handle the event (I don't know how parent component or data looks like so this is more pseudo-code...)

```html
<Rating :itemId="track.itemId" :rating="track.rating" @onRate="changeRating" />
```

```js
methods: 
  changeRating: function(id, rating) {
    let trackIndex = this.tracks.indexOf(track => track.itemId === id)
    this.tracks[trackIndex].rating = rating
  }
```